# Managing the adds and removes from arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a couple of arrays that are stored in sessions.  The purpose is to be able to add and remove objects from the arrays which will contain recipients to messages posted.  It SEEMS to be working okay but with some quirks.

This code allows objects to be added;

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $contact = $row['contact'];
  $userid = $row['userid'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='mypagepost.php?contact=$userid&recipient=$contact' STYLE='TEXT- DECORATION: NONE'><font color=#808080>" . $row['contact'] . "</a></font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $contact_count++;
  }
```

And this one gives me the ability to send to another page for removal from the respective arrays.

```
<?php
$isBefore = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['contactlist'] AS $key => $rec)
{
  if (!in_array($rec, $isBefore)) {
    $isBefore[] = $rec;
    echo "<font color=#808080><a href='removerecipient.php?contact=" . $_SESSION['recipientlist'][$key] . "&recipient=$rec' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>
<font color=#808080>" . $rec . " </a></font>";
  }
}
?>
```

This references a page with the following;

```
unset($_SESSION['recipientlist'][array_search($contact, $_SESSION['recipientlist'])]);

unset($_SESSION['contactlist'][array_search($recipient, $_SESSION['contactlist'])]);
```

So, I'm just starting to learn how to use arrays effectively so please forgive me for asking an obtuse question or two.  When I click on a recipient just once to add them to the arrays, it works fine.  I find that I can click on recipients in a contact list multiple times and the array still allows them to be added over and over again (although it doesn't print them out in the list).  When I go to remove them by clicking on their name, I have to click them over and over again until they're gone.  How can I set up a situation where it only gets added once and that's it?  The other question I have is that after I remove all recipients from an array, I'm still left with an index number with no value.  The print looks like this for both arrays (this is after adding and removing three recipients from the list;

```
Array ( [3] => )
Array ( [3] => )
```

The indexes don't apear to have a value associated with them, no idea what this means.

Comment: please don't use `<font>`

Comment: Dagon, does this tag have anything to do with the issue I'm working on?  I don't understand why this comment got upvoted, there's no detail or explanation or anything.  Odd.

Comment: 5 seconds on goggle would explain it. and no it does not effect your problem, but we are free to post comments on anything you post. if you find that odd, how long have you been on the internet ? :-)

Comment: Hi Dagon, I've been on the net for quite some time and my concept of odd is ever expanding.  Thank you for taking part in it.  I'll make a light suggestion to you - when you communicate, try to be clear.  I understand that something may look like a mistake to you, but "Google it" shouldn't be part of an answer when you're pointing out a mistake.  If you can't provide some kind of detail, then just don't point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `$_SESSION` and check to see

```
if(isset($_SESSION['nameHere'])){
  //do your thing here
}
```

, or make a variable like

```
$varName = 0;
```

and when the form is submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButtonName'])){
  if($varName === 0){
    $varName = 1;
    //do you thing here
  }
}
```

.  That `$_POST` would be a `$_GET` if your `<form method='get'` in your HTML.

Comment: Is there a way from preventing duplicates from being added to an array at the time that the items are being submitted?

Comment: You've got the code already for checking if(!in_array($1,$2)). Does this not work for you

Comment: Hi, user1641165.  This does not seem to work.  Should this syntax remove every instance of $userid and $recipient in an array?  I wonder if I can change it so that it searches the entire array and removes every instance - this way the duplicates would be removed as well.